# I've renamed directory, commited it and i cant do a push

Tags: git

Sorry, my question can be a bit noob but i dont have much experience with GIT. I've renamed directory "build" to "build1", comited changes and now i cant do a push, all i got is a message:

```
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 514 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: From /git/rololo
remote:    8432750..b53923c  master     -> origin/master
remote: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
remote:         build/build.html
remote:         build/build.unity3d
remote: Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
remote: Aborting
remote: Updating 1d2fa90..b53923c
```

What should i do now to perform a push?

Comment: Does `git status` show unstaged/uncommitted changes?

Comment: It looks like you need to investigate what the server hooks are trying to do.

Comment: @AndrewC yeah mate that helped because actually it was a problem on server side hook which was pulling changes to working directory after every push. And it was a problem of its repo, not mine :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do several things at this point.

> **1. stash your changes -> update the branch -> pop the stashed changes**

Stash the changes by:

```
git stash save <message>
```

then do a pull

```
git pull origin master
```

and then pop the stashed changes

```
git stash pop <stash>
```

**OR**

> **2. commit the changes to a new branch -> update the master -> merge the new branch to master**

checkout a new branch:

```
git checkout -b <new_branch>
```

commit the changes to the new branch:

```
git commit -m <commit message>
```

checkout the master and pull the changes in:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
```

merge the new branch which has the directory deleted:

```
git merge <new_branch>
```

Answer (score 1):

`git fetch` //You can now see the current state of affairs upstream.

At this point you may want to visualise branches in `gitk` or `gitg`.

You're probably in this situation:

> ```
> -A-B-C-D  //Master
>     \E-F  //Your branch, say you've done your renames in commit F
> ```

How you proceed depends how you want the history to appear:

#### Rebase

`git rebase` reparents your branch (`E-F`) from where you diverged (`B`) to the latest commit in master (`D`). You still have to resolve any conflicts with `C-D`:

> ```
> -A-B-C-D-E-F
> ```

#### Merge

`git merge origin/master` pulls down updates from upstream into your local branch:

> ```
> -A-B-C-D
>     \E-F-CD'
> ```

At this point you have to resolve with your rename conflicts. 
You've now got a merge-commit containing `C` and `D` on your local branch.

`git push`

> ```
> -A-B-C-D----G
>     \E-F-CD'/
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to `git pull` before renaming directories because files were changed inside that dir.

Comment: Ok, how can i do pull "before" renaming if i already renamed the directory and commited those changes?

Comment: You _could_ `rebase` onto the latest commit of your remote. You'd then be prompted to resolve conflicts.

Comment: rebase is not a good idea because files are moved. You should `git reset` to previous commit, `git pull`  and then rename dir and commit

Comment: @lukasz `git reset HEAD~1 --hard` will discard your renaming

Comment: git is quite capable of noticing files have been moved, rather than simply "file x is deleted, file foo\x is new". I would say that abandoning potentially-hard-to-resolve commits is a bad habit to get into.